# How to extract with sed a pattern starting with '('

Tags: regex, sed, pattern-matching

The output of `xdpyinfo | grep dimensions` is

```
  dimensions:    2560x1600 pixels (676x423 millimeters)
```

Piping it through `sed -r 's/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+x[0-9]+).*$/\1/')` does extract the dimensions in pixels (`2560x1600`), but won't work with the opening parenthesis.

How to get the dimensions in milimiters (i.e. `646x423`) with sed?

Comment: Escape the parenthesis with a backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract it in single command then you can just replace your existing `grep` command with this `gnu grep` using match reset regex i.e. `\K`:

```
xdpyinfo | grep -oP 'dimensions:.*\(\K\d+x\d+'

676x423
```

Above will require `gnu grep`. If that is not available to you then you can use this `grep` piped with another `grep`:

```
xdpyinfo | grep -oE 'dimensions:.*\([0-9]+x[0-9]+' | grep -oE '[0-9]+x[0-9]+$'
```

If you have to use `sed`, then use a single sed command as this and cut down `grep`:

```
xdpyinfo | sed -nE '/dimensions/{s/.*\(([0-9]+x[0-9]+).*/\1/p;q;}'
```

Comment: Don't have `ggrep` installed, but the second options does not output anything.

Comment: For `sed` I suggest using `xdpyinfo | sed -nE '/dimensions/{s/.*\(([0-9]+x[0-9]+).*/\1/p;q;}'` and cut down `grep`

Comment: Now yours is more complete and targets the full question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you extract the dimensions in pixels pattern (2560x1600) with this format?

Comment: `xdpyinfo | sed -nE '/dimensions/{s/.* ([0-9]+x[0-9]+).*/\1/p;q;}'` should work for that.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
sed -r 's/.*\(([0-9]+x[0-9]+).*/\1/'
```

See an [online demo](http://ideone.com/BbjWXz).

**Details**

- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible
- `\(` - a literal `(` (in POSIX ERE flavor you are using with `-r`)
- `([0-9]+x[0-9]+)` - Group 1 (later referred to with `\1` backreference): 1+ digits, `x`, 1+digits
- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible

Note you actually can omit both `^` and `$` here since there is a single whole line match with `sed`.

And here is an equivalent solution using a POSIX BRE regex:

```
sed 's/.*(\([0-9][0-9]*x[0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

Note that a `(`  denotes a literal `(` char in POSIX BRE, and `\(...\)` defines a capturing group here. Since `+` quantifier  is not supported by POSIX BRE, you may just use `[0-9][0-9]*` instead (1 digit and 0+ digits).